# FireFox 72.0.2 on Mac Stuck in "Remote Control" mode

Tags: python, macos, selenium, firefox

72.0.2 (64-bit) on MacOS 10.14.6 (18G3020)
Ran a python selenium script for automation and after that FF still shows the orange stripes bar and an icon which says "Browser is under remote control"

Rebooted machine but no luck.
Is there way to take out FF in normal mode now?

(Not able to access saved logins in this mode)

Thanks!

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Sounds like the default profile in Firefox has become corrupted or got changed.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Yes I was playing with profile to start FF with an extension enabled. For now, I have removed all profiles except `default`. Is it possible to rename `default`, start with fresh one and still not lose saved passwords?

Comment: I'm pretty sure saved passwords stay with the profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick.

- Setup FireFox sync account
- Create a new empty profile and make it default
- Restart FF with that profile
- Login to FF sync and get back bookmarks/saved logins etc.

Now FF is auto-filling passwords again.

Strange thing is that address bar still shows slanted orange/light orange stripes and "Browser is under remote control" but works like regular browser.