# Firefox 82.0.2 on Mac Stuck in “Remote Control” mode

Tags: firefox, cypress, mozilla, selenium-firefoxdriver

My issue is similar that of the user who posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067833/firefox-72-0-2-on-mac-stuck-in-remote-control-mode) earlier this year. I was doing some work automating tests with Cypress, and ended up in a state where the address bar indicates that the "browser is under remote control" with the robot icon but otherwise works as intended.

I have tried restarting my computer, uninstalling and reinstalling Firefox, "Refreshing Firefox" using the troubleshooting menu, and clearing the startup cache. Yet the problem persists.

This [older post](https://www.jondelamotte.com/blog/firefox-stuck-in-remote-control-mode/) is from a user who was using Selenium/gecko and he/she claims the `marionette.enabled` config value was getting in the way.

EDIT: Changing this did solve my issue! But after flipping the flag you must restart the application.

Firefox will be my primary browser either way, but I'm not a fan of the striped address bar. It's quite the eye sore!

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See EDIT above.

1. Navigate to `about:config`
2. Flip `marionette.enabled` to `false`
3. Restart browser